# Javascript createelement button not clickable

Tags: javascript, dom

Hello I'm building a todo app  with javascript. and i started to make  divs and buttons from creating with  document.createElement but  when i create buttons to remove lists  only one button which is written in html is clickable and remove div  ,other buttons that created with javascript not clickable,please can anyone tell me how to fix

```js
let menu = document.querySelector(".bs");
let btn1 = document.querySelector(".btn");
let btn2 = document.querySelector(".btn3");

let inp = document.querySelector(".input");
let bsd = document.querySelector(".sss");
let brs  = document.querySelector(".marker");

btn1.addEventListener("click", function(){
  
  let  br = document.createElement("DIV");
  br.className = "red";
  br.innerHTML = inp.value;
  menu.appendChild(br);
  
  let ttt = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  ttt.className = "marker";
  ttt.innerHTML = "Remove";
  br.appendChild(ttt);
  
});

brs.addEventListener("click", function(){
  
  let bred =  document.querySelector(".but");
  let drp =  document.querySelector(".red");
  bred.removeChild(drp);
  
});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  color: white;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.marker {
  background-color:white;
  border:none;
  padding:10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="but">
    <div class="red">
      <button class="marker">Remove</button>
    </div>

    <div class="bs"></div>
  </div>
  
  <input type="text" class="input">
  <button class="btn">Add</button>

  <button class="btn3">Remove</button>
</body>
```

that

Comment: You need to add the click listener to the "remove" buttons *when you create them*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the click listener to "remove" buttons *when you create them*.

The following does this:

```js
let menu = document.querySelector(".bs");
let btn1 = document.querySelector(".btn");
let btn2 = document.querySelector(".btn3");

let inp = document.querySelector(".input");
let bsd = document.querySelector(".sss");
let brs  = document.querySelector(".marker");

let addBr = () => {
  
  let br = document.createElement("DIV");
  br.className = "red";
  br.innerHTML = inp.value;
  menu.appendChild(br);
  
  let ttt = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  ttt.className = "marker";
  ttt.innerHTML = "Remove";
  br.appendChild(ttt);
  
  // This is the important change. Part of creating the .ttt element
  // is setting up its event listeners!
  ttt.addEventListener('click', () => br.remove());
  
};

btn1.addEventListener("click", addBr);

// Call `addBr` once to add the initial element
addBr();
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  color: white;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.marker {
  background-color:white;
  border:none;
  padding:10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="but">
    <div class="bs"></div>
  </div>
  
  <input type="text" class="input">
  <button class="btn">Add</button>

  <button class="btn3">Remove</button>
</body>
```

Comment: and a one question after adding todos how to keep todo results when browser refreshing ,any idea? i mean how to store these results?

Comment: and why is creating  one div before i click add ? i want page clean without any todo to then to create  individually todo items

Comment: The very last line of javascript calls `addBr` - taking out this line will result in an initially clean page. (I only put it there to imitate your example, where an item exists initially). Storing the results so that they are not lost upon refresh is a much different question, and I recommend you post a separate question about it!